# CSS Fix in page momvement

Tags: css

I wish to prevent my page from moving slightly to the left when a scrollbar appears on the page.

Example:

http://i56.tinypic.com/28033g2.png

Clearly it moves to the left slightly and I wish for that not to happen.

The CSS:
http://osix.co.uk/style.css - (If the page doesn't load, please hit the refresh button.)

Answer (score 4):

Add `html {overflow-y: scroll;}` to your CSS to always show the scrollbar, hence avoiding this issue.